How to return a valid json object instead of a string when using a native query where it has a JSON data column in PostgreSQL java 21 quarkus 3.91
I have a Quarkus project with a User entity containing a JSON-typed column for storing address details. The data from this column is currently being returned as a string instead of a JSON object in the API response. I want to correctly deserialize this data into a JSON object. Below is the relevant code and setup:
Entity:
java

package org.acme;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
import java.util.Map;

@Table(name = "user_test")
@Entity
public class User extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "address", columnDefinition = "json")
    public Map<String, String> address;
}

Service:
java
package org.acme;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Object[]> getUser() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_test";
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}

Controller:
java
package org.acme;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/api")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GreetingResource {
    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Path("/usr")
    public Object getUsers() {
        return userService.getUser();
    }
}

Response from API (localhost:8080/api/usr):
json
[
    [
        2,
        "{\"zip\": \"98765\", \"city\": \"Springfield\", \"street\": \"1234 Oak St\"}",
        "John Doe"
    ]
]

The address field is being returned as a JSON-encoded string, but I expect it to be a proper JSON object.
How can I modify my setup so the address field is correctly deserialized to a JSON object in the API response?

Just map the address object as an Address Pojo instead of a Map.
